# Uninstalling Erlang and RabbitMQ, using Write-Verbose to ensure sequencing

Tags: windows, powershell, installer, erlang, rabbitmq

I'm new at PowerShell and I like it.

I had the change to write a script that uninstall **Erlang** and **RabbitMQ** and I want the same script to then remove the **Erlang folder** and the **RabbitMQ folder**.

But in order to do so I need the script to respect the tasks order.

My way out was to use `Write-Verbose` (line 13) so the script needs to wait for the task to end in order to pass to the next task:

```
# Let's set some verbosity
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

function Check_Program_Installed($programName){
    $check = Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"  |
    Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*$programName*" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString

    If ($check.DisplayName) {
        $result = $check.DisplayName
        Write-Output "I found: $result, let's uninstall it!"
        $uninst = $check.UninstallString

        Write-Verbose $uninst
        Start-Process -FilePath $uninst -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait #-NoNewWindow

        Check_Program_Installed($programName)
    }
    Else{
        Write-Output "$programName is not installed"
        }   
}

# Erlang check and Uninstall
Write-Output "Checking if Erlang exist" 
Check_Program_Installed("Erlang")
# RabbitMQ check and Uninstall
Write-Output "Checking if RabbitMQ exist" 
Check_Program_Installed("Rabbit")

# These actions need to be executed ONLY after Erlang and RabbitMQ uninstall
Write-Output "Then we do action 1" 
Start-Sleep -s 3
Write-Output "Then we do action 2" 
Start-Sleep -s 3
Write-Output "Then we do action 3" 
Start-Sleep -s 3
Write-Output "Then we do action 4" 
Start-Sleep -s 3
Write-Output "Then we do action 5"
```

[image]

This is a very newbie approach but it's the only thing I came out with.

Is there a more elegant way to handle the task and avoid PowerShell to pass to the next task if the previous one isn't completed?

Comment: Can you show us the content of the `UnInstall` strings?

Comment: If the uninstall string has the `\i` switch, then I suggest replacing that by `\x`

Comment: @Theo, the content is "C:\Program Files\{your Erlang Version}\Uninstall.exe"

Comment: I'm afraid the `/qn` switch is for `.msi` files. In this case it is a `.exe`. Apparently, the Erlang _Installer_ has a `/S` switch for silently install. Perhaps that also applies for the Uninstall.exe? There may be more switches possible. In a commandline you could try `"C:\Program Files\{your Erlang Version}\Uninstall.exe" /?` to hopefully get help about accepted switches.

Comment: Thank you @Theo but is not a silent installation what I need. I want the script *not to pass to the next step* while is uninstalling Erlang. For now I'm piping everything into a Write-Verbose but this is a mere workaround